# How to create a dict from two tensors in tensorflow?

Tags: dictionary, tensorflow

I have two tensors - one for key and one for values. I am trying to create a dict from them so that I can use the created dict to update another dict using `update()` function. How can I implement this? I'm not looking for `tf.contrib.lookup.HashTable`.

I have tried using the `tf.map_fn` but it results in error given below.

```
s1 = tf.convert_to_tensor(['train-50.tfrecords','train-100.tfrecords','train-300.tfrecords'],tf.string)

s2 = tf.convert_to_tensor([0.01,0.03,0.04],tf.float32)

new_dict = dict(tf.map_fn(lambda x:(x[0], x[1]),(s1,s2),dtype=(tf.string,tf.
float32)))
```

> TypeError: cannot convert dictionary update sequence element #0 to a
>   sequence